# Unit testing conditional in ref (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I've run into a problem where I need to set indeterminate on a `input[type="checkbox"]`, as `indeterminate` isn't a html property I need to do this in the `DOM`, reading other answers I've decided to go with  `ref`

Code looks like:

```
<input
  id={props.id}
  checked={props.checked}
  type="checkbox"
  ref={(input) => {
    if (input) {
      input.indeterminate = props.indeterminate
    }
  }}
/>
```

Works fine, the problem is I can't think of a way to unit test the `if (input)` conditional

I am using Jest / Enzyme as my test frameworks

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use a data attribute instead? i.e. get rid of the ref and add `data-indeterminate={props.indeterminate}`

Comment: The `if (input)` also seems unnecessary and should always return true

Comment: Why do you need to set a non-standard attribute? What problem does this solve?

Comment: @DavidL.Walsh It is a standard attribute - https://w3c.github.io/html-reference/input.checkbox.html#input.checkbox-interface

Comment: Well there you go. Mea culpa! The following discussion may be of interest. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1798